# SQL - include empty fields

Tags: sql

I don't know if I worded my question correctly, but I'm new to SQL and I didn't really know how to word it. I am making a query about authors and the books they have written, and I want to include even the ones that have 0 books. How could I do this. This is my code, it is working correctly but it is leaving out the ones with 0 books:

```
SELECT surname as "Surname", forename as "Forename", COUNT(*) as "Books written"
FROM book
     LEFT OUTER JOIN author ON author.authorid = book.authorid
GROUP BY surname, forename
ORDER BY surname;
```

Comment: Can you show us some example data and the output you get, and the output you want?

Comment: Make author your leading table , instead of books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are starting at the wrong level. If you want all the authors you want start from authors. But, because you are starting from book it is saying give me all books for my criteria and join on the authors after.

```
SELECT surname as "Surname"
, forename as "Forename"
, COUNT(book.authorid) as "Books written"
   FROM author       
   LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON author.authorid = book.authorid
   GROUP BY surname, forename
   ORDER BY surname;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, sorry I did not change this. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @arahman Thank you, that did it and also I understood my mistake! I will accept your answer asap!

Answer (score 1):

You should invert your select x join, selecting from authors and then joining its books. Also, you have to change the count for the book.authorid property, since this is what you want to count.

```
SELECT surname as "Surname", forename as "Forename", COUNT(book.authorid) as "Books written"
   FROM author 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON author.authorid = book.authorid
   GROUP BY surname, forename
   ORDER BY surname;
```

The concept here is that you are getting all the authors in the database and joining then to its books (returning even the authors that don't have any books since its a LEFT JOIN) instead of selecting books and then joining to its authors.

Please refer to the following graphical representation for SQL JOINs clarification
[image: SQL JOINs graphical representation]

Image taken from [DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006)

Answer (score 0):

Use column name inside `count()` instead of `count(*)` :

```
SELECT a.surname as "Surname", a.forename as "Forename", COUNT(b.authorid) as "Books written"
FROM book b LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     author a 
     ON a.authorid = b.authorid
GROUP BY a.surname, a.forename
ORDER BY a.surname;
```